# How can sectional horizontal lists be aligned in columns?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on a portion of a website that deals with online orders and deliveries. It was originally table based but was to be switched over to list format.

HTML

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
                <h4>Items</h4>
                <ul>
                    <li class="product">Product 1</li>
                    <li class="producer"><a class="producerlink" target="_blank" href="http://www.hallsapplemarket.com">Producer 1</a></li>
                    <li class="price">$1.50/lb.</li>
                    <div class="input">
                    <li class="order"><input type="text" placeholder="amt. here" maxlength="15"></li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="underline"></div>
                </ul>
```

CSS

```
.product {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.producer {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 0 20% 0 25%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.producerlink {
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.price {
    font-size: 1em;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
}
.input {
    display: inline;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
.input .order {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-top: -1%;
    width: 100px;
    display: inline;
}
```

The full template is linked here:

https://jsfiddle.net/TLittler/a5dg1zko/5/

I'm currently using jQuery to structure collapsible lists which has worked well. However, I'm having difficulty aligning all the sections. I have margins set to space out the products, producers, and prices but the producers' and prices' positions are relative to how long the product name is. I am trying to align them in columns so each underlined section is aligned the adjacent sections, but I'm unsure of how to do so without using tables.

Comment: You can try CSS tables. And your markup is incorrect: `ul` can only contain `li` (or `script` or `template`), but not things like `ul`, `div`, `h4`.

Comment: What would be an alternative to divs inside the ul? Could I nest the ul in a div?

Comment: @Oriol `ul` can contain `li`, `ul` and `ol` ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul)).

Comment: @Freeeeez The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element) disagrees: "Zero or more `li` and [script-supporting](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#script-supporting-elements-0) elements."

Comment: @ThomasLittler You can wrap that invalid content inside one or more `li`.

Comment: @Oriol yep, it's deprecated in HTML5

Answer (score 0):

I think flexbox is a good method here. Add `display: flex;` to the `ul` and `width: 100%;` to each of the elements. I would also recommend using borders or a pseudo element for the underline.

Roughly, this would be the CSS:

```
ul {
   display: flex;
}
ul::after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 4% 0 3% 0;
    padding-top: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
ul > li, ul > div {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Here's some more about flexbox:

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

Comment: Would there be any other alterations to the CSS in addition to those properties?

Comment: The floats are obsolete (and probably break the flexbox) and the `display: inline` is not needed either.

Comment: I had to look a little into practices with flex but it worked great! Thank you!